# any php function to check domain is blacklisted or not. I am using checkdnsrr( $domain . '.', 'MX' ) but it is showing yopmail.com is valid

Tags: php, email, dns, blacklist

Please tell me any **PHP function** or **any method** to check domain name is **blacklisted** or not, I am using `checkdnsrr` but I think it is not good to use.

```
$notBlocklisted = checkdnsrr($explodeEmail[1] . '.', 'MX');
```

The above line is, I am using

Comment: `checkdnsrr()` has nothing to do with blacklists. Your code simply checks if there's a MX record, which yopmail.com has. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php): _"Returns TRUE if any records are found; returns FALSE if no records were found or if an error occurred."_

Comment: ...also, blacklisted _where_ and from _what_?

Comment: Than please tell me, what is the solution?

Comment: You need to answer my second comment before we can suggest anything.